# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first npgsql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, npgsql

I made my `reader.close()` and it does not work as well.
can you help me to resolve my problem.

```
IList<Borne> ListeBorne = new List<Borne>();
NpgsqlCommand maCommande2 = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from borne;", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader monReader2 = maCommande2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
NpgsqlCommand maCommandeEncaiss= new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from encaissement;", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader monReaderEncaiss = maCommandeEncaiss.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (monReaderEncaiss.Read())
{
    Encaissement encaiss = new Encaissement();
    encaiss.id = monReaderEncaiss.GetInt32(0);
    encaiss.mode_paiemant = monReaderEncaiss.GetString(2);
    encaiss.num_fact = monReaderEncaiss.GetString(9);
    ListEncaissement.Add(encaiss);
}

while (monReader2.Read())
{
    Borne b = new Borne();
    b.id = monReader2.GetInt32(0);
    b.nom = monReader2.GetString(2);
    ListeBorne.Add(b);
}

ViewBag.ref_borne = new SelectList(ListeBorne, "id", "nom");
ViewBag.num_fact = new SelectList(ListEncaissement, "id", "num_fact");
ViewBag.mode_paiement = new SelectList(ListEncaissement, "id", "mode_paiemant");
```

I added preload `reader = true` in connectionString web config but it did not work yet.

Comment: Using / Dispose is your friend - use em.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you can't use two readers on one connection at the same time, you have to close the first before executing the second.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close a reader before you can use another on the same connection.

You should use the `using`-statement for anything implementing `IDisposable` whenever possible:

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connection-string"))
{
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from encaissement", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var encaiss = new Encaissement();
                encaiss.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                encaiss.mode_paiemant = reader.GetString(2);
                encaiss.num_fact = reader.GetString(9);
                ListEncaissement.Add(encaiss);
            }
        }
    }
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from borne", conn))
    {
        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var b = new Borne();
                b.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                b.nom = reader.GetString(2);
                ListeBorne.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-open connection on 2nd command? Or does it stays open till it hits end of conn?

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan: it's not closed because it's in the same `using(var conn...)` scope

Comment: thanks it work.
But i remove  while (monReader2.Read()) in
 using (NpgsqlDataReader monReaderEncaiss = maCommande2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (monReaderEncaiss.Read())
            {
                while (monReader2.Read())
                {
               }
            }
        }
because monreader2 is not declared

Comment: @Chaimachouchou: well, i haven't used it either. Look at my code

Answer (score 0):

"While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it." - msdn.

Normally you might have to *manually* close a connection. But if you use `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` the "Connection object is closed when the associated *DataReader* object is closed." - msdn.

```
IList<Borne> ListeBorne = new List<Borne>();

NpgsqlCommand maCommandeEncaiss= new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from encaissement;", conn);    
NpgsqlDataReader monReaderEncaiss = maCommandeEncaiss.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (monReaderEncaiss.Read())
{
    Encaissement encaiss = new Encaissement();
    encaiss.id = monReaderEncaiss.GetInt32(0);
    encaiss.mode_paiemant = monReaderEncaiss.GetString(2);
    encaiss.num_fact = monReaderEncaiss.GetString(9);
    ListEncaissement.Add(encaiss);
}
monReaderEncaiss.Close();

NpgsqlCommand maCommande2 = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from borne;", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader monReader2 = maCommande2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);   

while (monReader2.Read())
{
    Borne b = new Borne();
    b.id = monReader2.GetInt32(0);
    b.nom = monReader2.GetString(2);
    ListeBorne.Add(b);
}
monReader2.Close();

etc...
```

Comment: ...sry, didn't see the other answer. i took a long time to write this up... and i think i forgot to open the conn...